# How to define Helper Class with generics and inheritance?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I'm trying to setup an helper class, that based on generics, should call methods in generic class type:

```
static class Helper<T> where T : IWorkingPhase
{

}
```

```
interface IWorkingPhase
{
   GetListViewModel();
}
```

```
abstract class BaseWorkingPhase: IWorkingPhase
{
   public abstract GetListViewModel()
   {
  
   }
}
```

```
class PhaseA : BaseWorkingPhase
{
   public override GetListViewModel()
   {
  
   }
}
```

```
class PhaseB : BaseWorkingPhase
{
   public override GetListViewModel()
   {
  
   }
}
```

What i'm trying to achieve is some similar to:

```
var a = Helper<PhaseB>.GetListViewModel();
```

How should i configure this all?

I was thinking of linking the generic with 'new()', but is this correct for a hypothetical future use of dependency injection?

Or should i set as static the "GetListViewModel" method, in the classes?

Comment: What instance of `IWorkingPhase` should `Helper<T>` call the `GetListViewModel()` method on?

Comment: I was thinking of setting the method as "static" as it doesn't work with instance data, it retrieves data from the database using Entity framework DBContext

Comment: _"it retrieves data from the database"_ - in that case: look up "Repository" and "UnitOfWork" patterns.

Comment: I already use an unit of work in a repository for data access layer

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for:

```
static class Helper<T> where T : class, BaseWorkingPhase, new()
```

Or:

```
static class Helper<T> where T : BaseWorkingPhase
```